Adding data source dynamically into Abstract Routing Data Sources in Java Spring Boot application
I have a multi tenant Java application running that uses Abstract Routing Data Sources to implement multi tenancy. Each "Key"-"Value" pair represents a tenant and I am trying to add a new "key"-"Value" pair into the Abstract Routing Data Sources when a new tenant logs in. Right now the data sources are configured on startup and tenants already exist. I want to handle the case when a new tenant joins while the application is running, without restarting the application.
I tried adding a new method "addDatasource" to handle this like shown below.
public class MultitenantDataSourceAbstractRoutingDS extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

  @Override
  protected String determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return ApTenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
  }


  @Override
  protected DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
    return super.determineTargetDataSource();
  }

  private final Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    super.setTargetDataSources(this.targetDataSources);
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
  }

  public void addDataSource(String key, ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
    this.targetDataSources.put(key, dataSource);
    super.setTargetDataSources(this.targetDataSources);
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
  }


But the the entity manager and transaction manager associated with this won't get updated both of which are beans and are initiated on startup.
